# How to get list of all sobject records modified today in the system?

Tags: apex, soql, query, salesforce-id, sosl

I need a list of all sobject records that got modified today. this is not just for one object but for all objects in the system. Is there a simpler way to do this? 
Please reply.

Comment: Hello @The Beginner, Have you tried anything so far? As you mentioning that you need some simpler solution, please share code which you have tried.